# Regex for Domains?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to clean up lists of websites using regex. This is a sample line from the text file I will feed through the script:

```
419     pcpop.com   IT  4,675
420     1234567.com.cn      Finanace    4,512
424     shanxi.gov.cn   Others  3,633
425     lss.gov.cn      Others  5,513
426     meishij.net     Local Information   5,450
```

the goal is to only pull the domains out:

```
meishij.net, shanxi.gov.cn, etc
```

This is what I have so far:

```
re.findall(r"\w+\.com|\.cn|\.ru|\.gov|\.cc|\.life|\.net|\.org", ...
```

Which works fine for .com:

```
['it168.com']
['alibaba.com']
['.cn']
['.cn']
```

but any other top level domains besides .com only pulls the top level domain itself instead of the entire domain name. I thought using `|` as `OR` would work to cycle through top level domains to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some old-fashioned but powerful string functions:

```
junk = """
419     pcpop.com   IT  4,675
420     1234567.com.cn      Finanace    4,512
424     shanxi.gov.cn   Others  3,633
425     lss.gov.cn      Others  5,513
426     meishij.net     Local Information   5,450
"""

domains = [parts[1].strip()
           for line in junk.split("\n") if line
           for parts in [line.split()] if len(parts) > 1]
print(domains)
```

Which yields

```
['pcpop.com', '1234567.com.cn', 'shanxi.gov.cn', 'lss.gov.cn', 'meishij.net']
```

---

If you insist, you'd need to form a non-capturing group around your alternations:

```
re.findall(r"\w+(?:\.com|\.cn|\.ru|\.gov|\.cc|\.life|\.net|\.org)")
#              ^^^
```

Comment: Yea im just going to use string functions, its much easier, the regex is killing my brain. The modificatiosn you made to the RegEx only captured the first tld, but the string functions worked better. Thanks for the help.